# Ajuda com Foreign Key, MySQL - Xampp

Tags: mysql

**Banco de dados MySQL**
**Pergunta 1:**
Estou tentando deletar uma Foreign Key e está dando esse erro: 
#1044 - Acesso negado para o usuário ''@'' ao banco de dados 'information_schema'

**Código:** `alter table informacoesproduto drop foreign key informacoesproduto_ibfk_1;`


**Pergunta 2:**
Queria saber como renomear uma Foreign Key, pois quando eu fui criar, acabei botando um caracter especial no nome(+), então agora não estou conseguindo deletar.
**Código:** `alter table informacoesproduto drop foreign key fk_exemplo+teste;`

Comment: Lupart, faça apenas uma pergunta por página.

Answer (score 0):

**Pergunta 1:**
Como o erro mostra, teve o acesso negado. Isso pode ser porque o usuário que está logado não tem permissão na tabela "informacoesproduto", precisa confirmar.

Para ver as permissões, use o comando:  `show grants for 'usuario'`

**Pergunta 2:**
Não é possível renomear uma *constraint*, você precisa apagar (`drop foreign key`)  e criar novamente. Coloque o nome entre aspas:

```
alter table informacoesproduto drop foreign key `fk_exemplo+teste`,
      add constraint `nome-correto` foreign key (`nome-do-campo) references `nome-da-tabela`(`nome-do-campo-na-outra-tabela`);
```

Comment: Quem negativou poderia por obséquio apontar aonde se encontra informação equivocada nessa resposta?